# Writing HTML code inside variable in ASP.NET C# and Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new in ASP.NET C# and I have problems with some things.

In PHP, I can store HTML code inside a variable, for example:

```
$list = "<li>My List</li>";
echo "<ul>{$list}</ul>"; // write <ul><li>My List</li></ul>
```

I tried this in ASP.NET and Razor

```
string List = "<li>My List</li>";
<ul>@List</ul>
```

But ASP changes "<" and ">" to `&gt;` and `&lt;`.. You know any solution for this?

I have another question, can I insert variable inside a quotes like PHP?

```
echo "<ul>{$list}</ul>";
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The Razor engine HTML encodes strings by default, as you have noticed.  To avoid this behavior, just use [`Html.Raw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

```
<ul>@Html.Raw(List)</ul>
```

**Edit**

To render a variable within a string, I suppose you could use `string.Format`:

```
@{ var someVariable = "world"; }
@string.Format("<div>hello {0}</div>", someVariable)
```

Although that seems like overkill (at least for this example) when you can just write:

```
<div>hello @someVariable</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, it works. And the other question? I can write a variable inside quotes like php? Ill select correct answer in 9 mins, thanks again.

Comment: @Carasuman no prob, glad it helped -- see my update above, if that helps.

Comment: This also works: `<span class="hidden" data-state="@(entry.Key)_Title">`

Check out http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Core 6.0 you can use [MarkupString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#raw-html) like this:

```
@((MarkupString) yourString)
```